# Can the encoder and decoder have different hidden dimensions in the Transformer architecture?

Tags: attention, transformers, seq2seq

In the vanilla Transformer architecture, can we have an encoder with hidden size of 768, and a decoder with hidden size of 792?

Comment: What do you call Vanilla Transformer here? The base architecture from the Attention is all you need paper has 512 dimensions both in the encoder and the decoder. The dimensions can be different, the projection into heads will take care of that.

Comment: Yes; I don't think I've seen a setup w/ a different encoder/decoder hidden state size, but I suppose it's possible in theory. I have seen setups with different numbers of encoder and decoder layers quite often though.